# Subtracting multi-column dataframe & a single value dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

**Question 1:**
I have a multi column dataframe and I want it subtracted to a single value dataframe. How would I tackle this with pandas? Below I want to subtract df1 & df2...

```
import pandas as pd

df1_header = [['OUT1', 'OUT2', 'OUT3', 'OUT4', 'OUT5', 'OUT6']]
df1_values = [[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1_values, columns=df1_header)

df2_values = [[10]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2_values)

Desired output:
OUT1 OUT2 OUT3 OUT4 OUT5 OUT6
0   1   2   3   4   5
```

**Question 2:**
What if I have a **multi column & row** dataframe and I want it subtracted to a **multi column but single row** dataframe? Below I want to subtract df1 & df2...

```
import pandas as pd

df1_header = [['OUT1', 'OUT2', 'OUT3', 'OUT4', 'OUT5', 'OUT6']]
df1_values = [[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
              [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1_values, columns=df1_header)

df2_values = [[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2_values)

Desired output:
  OUT1 OUT2 OUT3 OUT4 OUT5 OUT6
   0    0    0    0    0    0
   6    6    6    6    6    6
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print(df1.sub(df2.to_numpy()))
```

Prints:

```
  OUT1 OUT2 OUT3 OUT4 OUT5 OUT6
0    0    1    2    3    4    5
```

---

For the second example the output is:

```
  OUT1 OUT2 OUT3 OUT4 OUT5 OUT6
0    0    0    0    0    0    0
1    6    6    6    6    6    6
```

---

EDIT: Changed `.values` to `.to_numpy()`

Comment: Thanks this worked great! How would I remove the indexing on numpy?

Comment: @enteng_kamote What do you mean by *remove indexing*? You don't want to show the index? You can save the dataframe to CSV using `index=False` and it will save without it.

Comment: NVM, you're right I can just use pandas to write to CSV.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.subtract` for this usecase:

```
np.subtract(df1,df2)
```

Outputs:

case1

```
   OUT1  OUT2  OUT3  OUT4  OUT5  OUT6
0     0     1     2     3     4     5
```

case2:

```
   OUT1  OUT2  OUT3  OUT4  OUT5  OUT6
0     0     0     0     0     0     0
1     6     6     6     6     6     6
```

Comment: This works as well, why does the first answer needs `.to_numpy?`

Comment: @enteng_kamote since pandas subtraction is index and columns aligned so it matches index and column names and only when matched, does it performs a subtraction. While this answer uses numpy's element wise subtraction which doesnot need index and column keys

Comment: Got it that makes total sense. Thanks!